# Could not launch Instance using Ubuntu Private AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-security-group

I launched an instance from a Private AMI (Ubuntu Machine Axon 5 testing - ami-0ab3a4010a1aad0a1(64-bit (x86))), (I took the Image on last month from my Production Server.) and found that I could not connect ssh into the instance. I received the error Connection timed out.

I checked the security groups to verify that Port 22 was associated with 0.0.0.0/0. Additionally, I checked the route tables to verify that 0.0.0.0/0 is associated with target gateway attached to the VPC.

I find that only 1/2 status checks have passed -1. System status checks - passed
the instance status check failed. Error showing **"Instance reachability check failed"**.

Answer (score 0):

From [Status checks for your instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html):

> There are two types of status checks: system status checks and instance status checks.
>
> - **System status checks** monitor the AWS systems on which your instance runs. These checks detect underlying problems with your instance that require AWS involvement to repair. When a system status check fails, you can choose to wait for AWS to fix the issue, or you can resolve it yourself. For instances backed by Amazon EBS, you can stop and start the instance yourself, which in most cases results in the instance being migrated to a new host.

> - **Instance status checks** monitor the software and network configuration of your individual instance. Amazon EC2 checks the health of the instance by sending an address resolution protocol (ARP) request to the network interface (NIC). These checks detect problems that require your involvement to repair. When an instance status check fails, you typically must address the problem yourself (for example, by rebooting the instance or by making instance configuration changes).

It sounds like something is badly configured on your AMI, or it was launched on a different Instance Type that does not support the operating system installed on that AMI (eg Intel vs ARM). You *might* be able to see something with **Actions → Monitor and troubleshoot → Get system log**.

Worst case, you can mount the disk on another instance to extract data files.

Comment: I have launched the new instance with same old configuration and instance type but still error occurs. I have mounted this disk with another Ubuntu instance still error showing. I checked the system log there two or more services are failed.  Please help             [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start LSB: Jitsi conference Focus. [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Project Controller Service.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Sample Worker Service.